# Solving N for HN=0, Given H is a special type of skew symmetric (n x n, n is a odd number) matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, problem-solving, matrix-equations

Solving $N\  \mathrm{for}\ H \times N =0$, given $H$ is a special type of skew symmetric matrix $(n \times n, n\ \mathrm{is\ an\ odd\ number}\ n=2k+1)$, 0 on diagonal and 1, -1 in off-diagonal entries. Each row and column in **H** has exactly k 1s and k -1s and one 0. N is a $n \times 1$ vector satisfies $N' \times 1\ n=1$. All entries in **N** is non-negative.
Naturally, **N**' = (1/n, 1/n, ..., 1/n) is one of the solutions, my question is there any other solutions or this solution is a unique one? If so, how to prove this?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: I figured it out now, thanks for all!